# Confirm crontab

Tags: cron

Just want someone to confirm this is the correct cron configuration to have the server restart Apache every Sunday night. I have never done a cron command which had a space in it, so want to make sure it's correct.

```
0 3 * * 0 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, why are you restarting Apache on a `cron` - furthermore why with a `SIGKILL` (restart) statement rather than `SIGHUP` (graceful)

This is a much "friendlier" means of restarting Apache, so that you don't kill off existing sessions.

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful
```

Your cron will kill and start Apache at 3am on Sunday.

Bear in mind, different OS'es have different possible notation for Sunday on a crontab - it could be any of:

```
0 3 * * sun
0 3 * * 0
0 3 * * 7
```

And if you don't want to be harassed via email, you can discard `STERR` and `STOUT` by appending this to the end of your command

```
> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it's not the best thing but there is some Apache connection which keeps crashing the server, so hoping this is a temp fix until we can migrate off.

Comment: A better solution (short of fixing the root cause) would be to use a watchdog application like `monit`

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me, I guess. You might want to redirect output somewhere, even if it's just /dev/null. Otherwise cron will start trying to email you.